# .desktop shortcuts aren't working for java applications in LXDE

Tags: linux, java, jar, lxde

I just installed minecraft on my LXDE desktop/Lubuntu machine and I'm trying to create a .desktop file on the desktop that executes `java -jar ~/minecraftlauncher.jar`. The command works in bash scripts and the terminal but refuses to work when I click on my .DESKTOP shortcut which is suppose to execute the same command. I've experimented with other jars and they can't seem to start too.

Here is my xsession log:

```
** (pcmanfm:1572): DEBUG: launch command: <java -jar ~/Downloads/minecraft_server.jar>
** (pcmanfm:1572): DEBUG: sn_id = pcmanfm-1572-administrator-Dimension-3000-java-14_TIME14031891
Unable to access jarfile ~/Downloads/minecraft_server.jar
** (pcmanfm:1572): DEBUG: launch command: <java -jar ~/minecraftlauncher.jar>
** (pcmanfm:1572): DEBUG: sn_id = pcmanfm-1572-administrator-Dimension-3000-java-15_TIME14070158
Unable to access jarfile ~/minecraftlauncher.jar
```

UPDATE:
Whoops, it seems to work when I give an absolute path. I guess the home path is something else.
UPDATE:
I guess X doesn't resolve the home specifier. I ran a .desktop file that executed a script that outputs the current directory, and it seems to be correct.

Comment: Your X session log says...?

Comment: Oh, didn't realize I could trace the problem there. Hm, I'll update the question.